# is there a way to make makefile compile any file with any name?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

this is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
all:    #target name
        gcc project.c -o project cs50.c
```

it only compiles files with the name "project.c"
but i want it to also compile with files with any other name.

for example if my file name is "test.c" can it compile it to "test.exe" without changing the makefile to "gcc test.c"?

is that possible?

i tried replacing the file name with * but it didnt work

Comment: There are *innumerable* `Makefile` templates out there that work on arbitrary files.

Comment: Did you try defining a `$(NAME).exe: $(NAME).o` rule, and then running `make NAME=test`?

Comment: `%.o : %.c` is a pre-defined rule, as described in `10.5.2` in the `make` manual and  leads to 
       `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@`  bind `.o` to `.c` files

Comment: Since you tagged `c++`, you should verify that your *makefile* is calling out `g++` when you are compiling C++.

Comment: Your post doesn't mention C++, so why the `c++` tag?  They are distinct languages, for example C++ allows for operator and function overloading, the C language doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for are [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html), which given a pattern can make multiple outputs.   So for example, as mentioned in the comments, you can do:

```
%.exe : %.c
   $(CC) $*.c -o $@ cs50.c
```

This will build anything with an `exe` extension given a `.c` file with the same *stem* (the filename part that the `%` refers to).   In this recipe the `$*` expands to the stem's name. (see [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html))

In the above rule, all files will be compiled against `cs50.c`.   If you want instead to have some target specific file lists, you could do something like:

```
.PHONY: all
all: project.exe

EXTRA_FILES_project := cs50.c
EXTRA_FILES_blah := blah.c

%.exe : %.c
   $(CC) $*.c -o $@ $(EXTRA_FILES_$*)
```

Notice that there are by default a number of [Implicit Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) that already describe how to make a .o file from a .c file, etc.  There's lots of other tricks with these as well.  You might also want to read up on [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html), as these may be more what you're looking for.

Comment: i have done 
%.exe : %.c
   $(CC) $*.c -o $@ cs50.c

but it doesnt add the "cs50.c" resulting to a undefined reference error. it just compiles with "gcc (name).c -o (name)".

Comment: i have fixed it.

for some reason changing the "%.exe : %.c" to "%: %.c" worked

Comment: Changing it to `%: %.c` changes the fundimental behavior -- are you trying to build `project` or `project.exe`?     Note that `%: %.c` is a [match-anything rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html#:~:text=When%20a%20pattern%20rule's%20target,target%20or%20as%20a%20prerequisite.), which you want to avoid.   Note:, I originally had an extra colon after `all: project.exe:` -- perhaps this was causing your issue?  (I've updated the code)